# ServiceStack Can not get real exception message

Tags: exception, servicestack

### Server Side

`public class MyServices : Service
    {
        public object Get(Hello request)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("test error message");
            //return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, {0}!".Fmt(request.Name) };
        }
    }`

### Client Side

`try
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost:28586/");
        var response = client.Get<HelloResponse>(new Hello { Name = "DHJ" });
    }
    catch (WebServiceException ex)
    {
      // ex.ErrorCode = "InvalidOperationException" // No Problem.
      // ex.ErrorMessage = null // always null. Why?
    }`

And i saw the docs of ServiceStack like below:

> Throwing C# Exceptions
>
> In most cases you won’t need to be concerned with ServiceStack’s error handling since it provides native support for the normal use-case of throwing C# Exceptions, e.g.:
>
> public object Post(User request) 
>   {
>       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Name))
>           throw new ArgumentNullException("Name");
>   }
>   Default Mapping of C# Exceptions to HTTP Errors
>
> By Default C# Exceptions:
>
> Inheriting from ArgumentException are returned with a HTTP StatusCode of 400 BadRequest
>   NotImplementedException or NotSupportedException  is returned as a 405 MethodNotAllowed
>   AuthenticationException is returned as 401 Unauthorized
>   UnauthorizedAccessException is returned as 403 Forbidden
>   OptimisticConcurrencyException is returned as 409 Conflict
>   Other normal C# Exceptions are returned as 500 InternalServerError
>   This list can be extended with user-defined mappings on Config.MapExceptionToStatusCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `HelloResponse` class needs a `ResponseStatus` property, from the [Error Handling docs](http://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#error-response-types):

### Error Response Types

The Error Response that gets returned when an Exception is thrown varies on whether a conventionally-named `{RequestDto}Response` DTO exists or not.

#### If it exists:

The `{RequestDto}Response` is returned, regardless of the service method's response type. If the `{RequestDto}Response` DTO has a **ResponseStatus** property, it is populated otherwise no **ResponseStatus** will be returned.  (If you have decorated the `{ResponseDto}Response` class and properties with `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` attributes, then **ResponseStatus** also needs to be decorated, to get populated).

#### Otherwise, if it doesn't:

A generic `ErrorResponse` gets returned with a populated **ResponseStatus** property.

Comment: yes, you're right, but does it means i must to add a property "ResponseStatus" on each ResponseDTO every time? And i think that's not a good idea.

Comment: @LeoDeng please re-read my answer, you only have to add a `ResponseStatus` property if your Response DTO follows the `{RequestDto}Response` naming convention, if it doesn't ServiceStack will use the generic `ErrorResponse` DTO for errors which already contains the `ResponseStatus` property so your Response DTO doesn't need it.

Comment: @LeoDeng I've already covered this so please read my answer very, very carefully. If you have a `HelloResponse` DTO you **need to add your own ResponseStatus** property because ServiceStack will use your `HelloResponse` DTO if it exists so if your Response DTO doesn't have a ResponseStatus property ServiceStack has nothing to inject the Error Response into. If you **don't** have a `HelloResponse` DTO, i.e. there is no class called `HelloResponse` then ServiceStack will use the generic `ErrorResponse` DTO.